# Reload dynamically defined helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to define view helpers in Rails 5.2.0 on runtime (from within some code that lies within my lib folder and / or some initializer) and I came up with this approach so far:

```
def new_module
  Module.new do
    def self.create_method(name, &block)
      define_method(name, &block)
    end
  end
end

def define_dynamic_helper(name, &block)
  helpers = new_module
  helpers.create_method(name, &block)
  ActionView::Base.send :include, helpers
end
```

Now that I can define dynamic modules that get include into `ActionView::Base` on runtime, I call them e.g. in my controller like this:

```
define_dynamic_helper("my_helper") do
  "some data"
end
```

And my view uses the helper like this

```
<%= my_helper %>
```

But this has a drawback during development: When I remove the line that defines my helper, it is still available but I would expect a `MethodMissing` error. And as you can guess, this can lead to very complicated situations to debug.

So I got two questions here:

> - Is it possible to completely remove all dynamic helpers when Rails does a reload during development? Is there some kind of hook I can use?
> - Is using `ActionView::Base.send :include, helpers` the right approach for this? Or is there another entry point that I could use (which maybe provides a better reloading approach?)

Comment: Have you already tried `spring stop`?